# diurnal is to day as "..." is to morning

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I am looking for a term to replace formulations like "the activities of the morning", "the rituals pertinent to the morning", "the morning report" (that one is from the Lion King, I couldn't resist). I tried perusing the internet search engines of my knowledge, including some searches on merriam webster's website, but I can't get a hold of what I am looking for. In fact, [I will eat a better breakfast and pray every morning, now](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=pertinent%20to%20the%20morning&ia=web).

[image: search results for pertinent to the morning]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105105/discussion-on-question-by-thymaro-diurnal-is-to-day-as-is-to-morning).

Answer (score 79, accepted):

> **matutinal**  adjective   [formal]
>
> happening in the morning:
>
> - *We chatted over our matutinal coffee.*

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matutinal)]

Though normal people have morning coffee.

Comment: I don't think I or anybody in my family would be able to pay for matutinal coffee.

Comment: @Lambie I think I said that; OP _does_ also ask for a corresponding term to 'diurnal'.

Comment: I upvoted your answer and added: but it is highly literary.

Comment: 'Though normal people have morning coffee' was saying '_matutinal is highly literary_' in a way that's not highly literary (or really, formal; it's doubtless used in some sciences).

Comment: +1 for "normal people have morning coffee". :)

Comment: Matutinal? I can't spell 'morning' before ....

Comment: @EdwinAshworth In biology we say Crepuscular, but that actually refers to hours on either side of dawn AND dusk. Never heard of matutinal :)

Comment: Adam, that's a _stipulative definition_ for 'crepuscular', for once broader than the default 'everyday' one, which refers to twilight but not dawn. It's used in poetry, I seem to remember.

Answer (score 25):

I think I would use ***matinal***, which the OED holds to have the same meaning as ***matutinal***. However the latter they designate as *now chiefly literary*.

The examples they provide, for ***matinal*** across three main senses, are as follows:

> 1. = matutinal adj. 1.
>
> 1803   M. Charlton Wife & Mistress (ed. 2) II. i. 11   To attend the
>   matinal déjeuné's of old Gruffy in town.
>
> 1860   Ld. Lytton Lucile ii. v. §9. 30   The matinal chirp of a bird.
>
> 1862   Mrs. H. Wood Channings II. 74   Believing it could be nobody
>   less than the bishop come to alarm them with a matinal visit.
>
> 1908   J. Davidson Testament 37   The earth with its seas and its
>   skies, Its flowers and its matinal dew.
>
> 1991   E. S. Connell Alchymist's Jrnl. (1992) 100   Wounds contracted
>   past noon are less auspicious than matinal injuries.
>
> 2. a. = matutinal adj. 2.
>
> 1819   H. Busk Vestriad v. 276   The grey-ey'd Hours climb up the
>   starry way To meet fair maidens matinal as they.
>
> 1842   F. Trollope Visit to Italy I. xiv. 219   As if my very matinal
>   son and myself had constituted the whole party.   1997   Church Times
>   11 Apr. 20/3   I am, metabolically speaking, one of Bishop Heber's
>   sons of the morning: a matinal man who is fast asleep before the
>   epilogue.
>       b. Entomology. Of, relating to, or designating insects that are only active in the early morning.
>
> 1970   Jrnl. Kansas Entomol. Soc. 43 251 (title)    Some competitive
>   relationships among matinal and late afternoon foraging activities of
>   caupolicanine bees.
>
> 1985   Biotropica 17 217   Visitors that remove nectar, but are
>   ineffective pollinators include seven Euglossa spp. and three species
>   of matinal butterflies (Hesperiidae).
>
> 1997   Jrnl. Thermal Biol. 22 453   Activity patterns are..either
>   matinal, crepuscular, or bimodal; essentially desert bees avoid heat
>   and adapt to cold desert dawns and dusks.

Comment: I feel like I have actually seen the word *matinal* before, as opposed to *matutinal*, but for what it’s worth, [Google ngrams shows far more usage, especially historical, of *matutinal*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=matutinal%2Cmatinal&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmatutinal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmatinal%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @KRyan, For what it's worth, "matinal" is commonly used in French. ("Matin" = morning in French, and -al is a pretty common suffix e.g. banal, artisanal, fatal, etc.)

Comment: Ah. That explains the origins of the word ["Matins"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/matins).

Comment: Matinal is used a lot in french for this exact purpose.

Comment: @KRyan though if you are using Google nGrams then [*morning coffee* is far more common than *matutinal coffee*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=matutinal+coffee%2Cmorning+coffee&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmatutinal%20coffee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmorning%20coffee%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Henry I was about to say the same in the generic case [morning as an adjective beats matutinal & matinal](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=matutinal%2Cmatinal%2Cmorning_ADJ&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmatutinal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmatinal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmorning_ADJ%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cmatutinal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmatinal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmorning_ADJ%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @OJFord Adjective "morning" is not always idiomatic, however.  How would you use "morning" to say "Whilst tea is served in the afternoon, coffee is matinal"?

Comment: @WS2 "Whilst tea is served in the afternoon, coffee is more often a morning drink". But that's not really the point, the graph shows the prevalence of 'morning' as an adjective and 'matinal', not how idiomatically 'morning' is being used as an adjective, or whether it could have been used idiomatically in the cases where 'matinal' was used.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use "matin", as in "matins" (morning devotions)?  I would even use "matinal", though it might not be in every dictionary.  "My usual matinal activities always include breakfast and prayers."

Comment: would you have sources for that? Personally, I like it, having partially grown up in French, but is it also English? Or have you just made it an English word? :)

Comment: Actually, this seems to be a false friend. In English the meaning seems to be different than in French, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matinal, https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matins

Comment: matins is a liturgical hour and is not matutinal.

Comment: @thymaro, the first link [you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525962/diurnal-is-to-day-as-is-to-morning#comment1282466_525963) give lists meaning (2) as 'early', so it seems to be not so false a friend.

Comment: @LSpice I would still argue it is, because, based on my current understanding of the terms 'matinal' (eng) and 'matinal' (fre) (after having read the answers here and dict entries for the respective terms, that is), I wouldn't translate the one into the other. Doing that would alter the meaning of a sentence using the words in one or the other language. Isn't that the meaning of a false friend? You know, like translating 'actual' (eng) to 'aktuell' (deu).

Comment: @thymaro Or translating "aktuall" to "actual"  - which I encountered in a software library.  It caused no end of confusion until we understood what had happened.

Comment: @thymaro, probably you are [right](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/525962/diurnal-is-to-day-as-is-to-morning/525963#comment1282704_525963).  I interpreted 'false friend' in the more restrictive sense that they are similar-sounding words that mean *different* things ([Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_friend)), not just in the broader sense that they are not literal translations of one another.

Comment: @thymaro: the equivalent of the religious "matins" in English would be, in French, "matines"

Comment: @WoJ oh like in "Frère Jacques"! I've never looked up that word, even though I always wondered what it's supposed to mean. :D

Comment: (American) I think in English your stumbling block is just going to be that most people aren't familiar with a religion that observes matins. But English does have "matinee" from matins, which more people are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to be obscure, "auroral" can mean "of or pertaining to the dawn" (from the Roman goddess of the dawn), though this usage is swamped by the atmospheric phenomenon. The variant "aurorean" is more restricted to the dawn meaning, but is also even more obscure.

(The Cambridge dictionary doesn't have the dawn meaning nor "aurorean"; Merriam-Webster does.)

Comment: Interestingly, it seems the goddess Aurora was derived from the Latin goddess [Matuta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mater_Matuta), who is the origin of all the matinal, matutinal type answers..